# Caixa para digitação

Tags: android, xml

Estou querendo implementar na minha aplicação o modelo parecido do google contacts. 
Já tentei colocar `app:civ_border_width="1dp"` no xml mas também não deu. 
Gostaria de fazer igual a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

na pasta `drawable` crie um novo arquivo xml com esse codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <solid android:color="#00ffffff" /> // Cor de fundo
       <stroke android:width="1.0dip" android:color="#ffd4d4d4" /> // tamanho e cor da borda
       <corners android:topLeftRadius="5.0dip" android:topRightRadius="5.0dip" android:bottomLeftRadius="5.0dip" android:bottomRightRadius="5.0dip" /> // Radius da borda
</shape>
```

E no seu `EditText` adicione o xml que voce criou como background:

```
android:background="@drawable/seu_xml"
```

Alias, `app:civ_border_width="1dp"` só pode ser utilizado com a biblioteca `CircleImageView`(civ é a abreviação).

Comment: Olha o erro que deu:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Projetos/Decorus/app/src/main/res/drawable/translucid.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 44; O destino da instrução de processamento correspondente "[xX][mM][lL]" não é permitido.`

Comment: Editei a resposta.